# How to deserialize Json String and get keys from object using c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is my code

```
""{\n  \"data\": [\n    {\n      \"listid\": \"\",\n      \"name\": \"\"\n    }\n  ]\n}""
```

In the above string was coming from server. I want to deserialize the string and get keys from array of objects. I tried using `JsonConvert.Deserialization` with `Dictionary` but it throws an exception. I also tried `JObject` and `JArray`. I want to get `listId, name` keys.

Comment: Have you tried the NewtonJsoft library, that seems to the favourite json serialiser at the moment.

Comment: @Slicc, [`JsonConvert`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm) is `json.net`. I just fixed tags. And to OP, please show your code and error if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to deserialise to your own type? This works for me:

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string deser = "{\n  \"data\": [\n    {\n      \"listid\": \"\",\n      \"name\": \"\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCollection>(deser);


    }
}


public class MyType
{
    [JsonProperty("listid")]
    public string ListId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<MyType> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got Solution, following code works fine

```
string json = "{\n  \"data\": [\n    {\n      \"listid\": \"\",\n      \"name\": \"\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<string> li = new List<string>();
        dynamic jsondata = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
        foreach (string key in jsondata["data"][0].Keys)
        {
            li.Add(key);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json library in C#

You need to create the corresponding Classes with the matching property names as that of the json array in C# in order to deserialize the json string to C# objects.

See the following code.

```
namespace StackOverflow.Test
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\n  \"data\": [\n    {\n      \"listid\": \"123\",\n      \"name\": \"Name\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";
            var lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Lists)) as Lists;
            var list = lists.Data.FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + list.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("List Id: " + list.ListId);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Lists
    {
        public List<Info> Data { get; set; }
    }

    class Info
    {
        public string ListId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```